# ¿Cómo puedo poner un código php, dentro de otro archivo php mediante JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main"); //Localizar el div principal

const newDiv = document.createElement("div"); //Crea el primer div (que va como hijo del div principal)
const newH2 = document.createElement("h2"); //Crea el h2 (que va de hijo del div secundario)

newDiv.setAttribute("class", "new");

newH2.innerHTML= "<?php echo $tittl_e; ?>"; //Aca es donde yo quiero que en mi html dentro del h2, se inserte el codigo de php

main.appendChild(newDiv);
newDiv.append(newH2);
```

```html
<div id="main">

</div>
```

Como puedo hacer para que desde mi js, inerte un codigo, con una funcion en un archivo php

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Tienes que recordar que PHP se interpreta en el servidor y JavaScript, en el cliente. Si tú pones etiquetas PHP dentro de un HTML, eso no se va a interpretar y volver algo porque el servidor ya procesó el script PHP y entregó un HTML estático resultante. Posiblemente necesitas preparar los elementos HTML, ocultarlos y manipular la visibilidad con JS. O llamar un script diferente PHP vía ajax y leer algún dato de sesión.

Comment: Resumen: ajax es la solucion, OJO que es una alternativa, ya que por el nada del mundo puedes hacer lo que dices.